# PHP popen('Start /B' $cmd, 'w') on localhost from different computer

Tags: php, xampp, localhost, popen

I'm working on a project where users on same localhost would be able to view and launch files from the browser using xammp.

***My setup is:***

1- (Computer A) Main computer host which runs the Xammp and content the shared local disk for files.

2- (Computer B) Another computer on the same network and have access to the shared local disk.

Now everything is working perfect from accessing the files and using the localhost from computer A to computer B on the same network.

But my issue is only with this code:
`pclose(popen('start /B '.'"C:\" "'.$get_file_url.'" &','w'));`

***When I request this code, results are:***

1- Computer A will launch the file application in a great way on same computer.

2- Computer B will launch the file application in a great way but on Computer A.

My localhost link is the IP address of Computer A , So whenever I request this code, It will will ask Computer A to launch the file, not the same computer I'm requesting from.

***I made a test*** where Computer B will keep using the localhost from computer A, but when it comes to request that code to launch files, I've used computer B localhost, then it worked great.

Any idea how can I request that code file from any computer on the network and make it launch files on the same computer not on Computer A ?

Thank you!

Comment: So you want PHP to be able to launch a program on the users computer?

Comment: Yes, even if you use exec($file_link) on any computer connect to the localhost, it will launch the file on the main server, so exactly what I want is to launch a program on the users computer when they use that code or exec() from the localhost

Comment: Do you think that would be a major security problem?  As it would effectively allow any server to run code on a visitors computer it would definitely not work (not matter if it's a local network or not)

Comment: It's on a localhost only and users are aware about that, is there any option can complete this process?

Comment: The issue is that code is working great if it was on the user computer, but when they request it from the localhost from main server, it will launch applications on the main server, not their computers

Comment: Remember that your PHP code is running on the server, not on the clients computer. To make it possible to run stuff on the clients computer, you'd need to have some kind of remote execution server that the PHP can call remotely, and security settings that allowed it, surely?

Comment: Thank you for replying, remote execution server? do you have any recommendation?